# Identify a bird

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I have taken this picture of a bird in university zoo in Tel Aviv. It was approximately 25 cm high and seemed to be a flightless species. Can somebody help me identify it?

[image: A bird]

Comment: They fly rather well when they want to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a Black Crowned Night Heron, *Nycticorax nycticorax*, in my opinion - you can read more about it [here](http://www.planetofbirds.com/black-crowned-night-heron-nycticorax-nycticorax-2). Key to it's identification is the shape of the body and bill, it's characteristic of species from the heron family such as the [green heron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_heron). The range is right and the red eye is a good clue too.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be a Black Crowned Night Heron indeed. The photographs on wikipedia page helped me to conform this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-crowned_night_heron .